# .htaccess - Mod Rewrite works on xampp but crashes on hosted server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use a .htaccess file to redirect urls like `http://localhost/app/search/?s=hello` to `http://localhost/app/search.php?s=hello`.

My code in the .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f

#Search
RewriteRule ^search/([-_0-9a-z]*)$ search.php$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

The problem: On my apache on my local machine all works perfectly. But when I put the project on my hosted server, I see the following:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /redirect:/search.php.php.php was not found on this
>   server.

The settings on the server für mod-rewrite also correct.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You just need this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```